# NGINX Multiple Reverse Proxies

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have two NodeJS backends running on port 3000 and 4000 in a ubuntu server with NGNIX installed.

I don't have any domain names but I want to use nginx as a reverse proxy *with my IP address* like this.

- xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/app1 => should forward all the requests to port 3000
- xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/app2 => should forward all the requests to port 4000

This is what I tried in NGINX configs, but NGINX returns 404 not found response.

In **/etc/nginx/sites-available** directory, I have modified **default** as this,

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location /app1 {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /app2 {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

How can I make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go**

Multiple http servers on localhost using different ports

```
server {
    server_name mydomain-01.com;

    location / {
      proxy_redirect http://localhost:8001 https://mydomain-01.com;
      ...
    }
}
server {
    server_name mydomain-02.com;

    location / {
      proxy_redirect http://localhost:8002 https://mydomain-02.com;
      ...
    }
}
```

Single http server on localhost using hostname based sites

```
server {
    server_name mydomain-01.com;

    location / {
      proxy_redirect http://s1.mydomain:4000 https://mydomain-01.com;
      ...
    }
}
server {
    server_name mydomain-02.com;

    location / {
      proxy_redirect http://s2.mydomain:4000 https://mydomain-02.com;
      ...
    }
}
```